# error: cannot find 'constAccountsPreference' in scope

Tags: flutter

I'm facing this error when running my app on iOS:

```
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/sbenati/Visual Studio Code Projects/flutter_graildo/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:31:52: error: cannot find 'constAccountsPreference' in scope
              let accounts = preferences.array(forKey: constAccountsPreference) as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]();
```

I searched over and found no answers anywhere.

This is a flutter app running on SDK 2.5.2. I tried 2.5.3 as well, and got the same. I'm attempting this from both a macOS 10.15 and 11.6. The app runs fine on macOS 11.6, but not on iOS (tried iOS14 and iOS 15).

I don't seem to face this issue when running Flutter SDK 2.2.3, but I have to change all of my packages (and code) to downgrade my app to that level.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently if you start a project in Flutter SDK < 2.0, and end up in SDK > 2.0, all the while not testing or updating your system on the iOS/macOS side, you end up with old files generated by Flutter that won't update themselves inside your ios folder.

The troublesome file in this case was AppDelegate.swift, and the code within was longer understood by Xcode, causing the above problem.

The solution was to manually handle your Apple side of things in your flutter app by deleting the ios folder, then following it with the following sequence of events/commands. I did not need to delete the macos folder because it wasn't giving any issues, probably because I never enabled building macos apps till recently, neither was this possible prior to SDK version 2.0.

1. Backup your project files.
2. in Terminal, run in project folder (notice the period at the
   end): flutter create .
3. Now your error is gone, and your app should run normally, but you
   are not done setting up. Access your ios folder > Podfile and make
   sure you have the right settings for the minimum ios version
4. From your backup, restore the app logo and any assets you
   attached to your project.
5. Open the project in Xcode and enter all the configuration
   manually. You can also import any previous project configuration
   files (such as info.plist) into your new ios folder.

The previous (erroneous) file contained the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let accountchannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.yourapp/channels",
                                                  binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        accountchannel.setMethodCallHandler({
          (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
          guard call.method == "getAccounts" else {
              result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
              return
            }
            self?.getAccounts(result: result)
        })

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }


  private func getAccounts(result: FlutterResult) {
          var data: [String] = [];
          let preferences = UserDefaults.standard;
          let accounts = preferences.array(forKey: constAccountsPreference) as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]();
          for account in accounts {
              data.append( account[constAccountName] as? String)
          }
          result(data);
  }
}
```

The new file, containing the right code, had this in comparison:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("your app id here")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

The above solution relies heavily on my analysis of what happened. I have not delved deeply into the specifics of what actually was going on. Hope it helps someone stuck in the future.

The current Flutter SDK is 2.5.3.